# Err 404 (Not Found) jquery partial view loading through script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, partial-views

My code looks like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("MyDropDownList")
    .BindTo(new string[] { "StringOne", "StringTwo", "StringThree"})
    .Events(e => e.Change("MyDropDownListOnchange")))
```

In the scripts:

```
function MyDropDownListOnchange() {
    var val = $("#MyDropDownList").val();
    $("#LoadingDiv").load("Views/StringView/_StringOne.cshtml");
```

I have tried several variations:

- "~/Views/......
- "../Views/.....
- "Views/....
- "ImageView/....

Error:

`//localhost:43222/Views/StringView/_StringOne.cshtml 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: What is the absolute path to your file: `//localhost:43222/???`

Comment: `//localhost:43222/Views/StringView/_StringOne.cshtml`

Comment: But it saying this file doesn't exists, so?...

Comment: Sry, thats what i assume it was when i pull the file into my Razor View it displays as follows `<a href="~/Views/StringView/_StringOne.cshtml">~/Views/StringView/_StringOne.cshtml</a>` but i have tried using /~/View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This way

```
function change() {
    var val = $("#OptionsDrop").val();

    //you will have to make a switch case here depending on how many options you have in the DDL

    $.ajax({
        url: '/StringView/GetStringOne',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#LoadingDiv').html(data);
        }
    });
```

This includes the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetStringOne()
{
    return PartialView("_StringOne");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#LoadingDiv").load("Views/StringView/_StringOne.cshtml");
```

remove the .cshtml try this :

```
$("#LoadingDiv").load("Views/StringView/_StringOne");
```

and make sure in your controller you have returned this partial view

something like

```
[httpget]
public PartialViewResult _StringOne()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: Same error `GET http://localhost:59464/Views/StringView/_StringOne 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I added in the code for the controller, as per answer, changed the script to `$("#LoadingPartialDataDiv").load("_" + val);` wich equates to "_StringOne" still doesnt to find it.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question above, I hvae rewrote some of your code, returns a different error.